# How to retrieve Post Excerpt from a different site in the Network

Tags: multisite, excerpt

Is it possible to get the post excerpt from a different site in my Multisite Network?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using [`switch_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) you can load another Wordpress site, get what you want, then revert back to your current site and carry forward any retrieved data.

```
// the different site ID in your Wordpress Network
$otherSite = 3;

// the post excerpt you're after in the different site
$otherSitesPost = 42;


switch_to_blog( $othersite );

$otherSitesPostExcerpt = get_post($otherSitesPost)->post_excerpt;

restore_current_blog();

echo "Site #{$otherSite} post #{$otherSitesPost} excerpt: {$otherSitesPostExcerpt}";
```

Comment: great, glad to help. if that answered the question for you be sure to mark it as answered! if you've got any more questions feel free to ask

Comment: I can't accept answers as a "guest". Sorry...